# Rails polymorphic assocation is saying undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations

I have a user model with a type column (i believe this is called a polymorphic association).  A user can be one of two types: employee or employer.  An employer can post projects.  So projects belongs_to employer and an employer has_many projects.  I have the following code in my projects controller:

```
def new
    @project = Project.new
end

def create
    project = current_user.project.build(project_params)
    project.save
    redirect_to project_path(project_params(:id))
end

def show
    @project = Project.find(params(:id))
end

private

def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:title, :category, :location, :budget, :description)
end
```

The problem is that when I try to submit the new form in the browser, i am told:

```
undefined method `project' for #<Employer:0x007ffd85cf3250>
```

I have made forms in rails many times.  The only thing I am doing differently is the polymorphic association so my guess is the problem has something to do with that?  Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks.  I also have a feeling my show method might be incorrect if anyone has any comments on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `projects` with s since you are use `has_many`. `project` method would only be available if you had said employer `has_one` project.

Note that `projects` would return an array of projects rather than project object.

Comment: If i do that, it tells me: 'wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)'

Comment: It highlights the line 'def project_params', which it would go to when calling the build method.

Comment: I'm wondering if you can call `project_params` at all. To check this, try placing `project_params` before `project = current_user.project.build(project_params)`. This would tell us if `project_params` is causing any problem.

Comment: OK.  I commented out the build line and replaced it with the single line 'project_params'.  When i did this, that line did not seem to cause any problems.  It just caused an error when  tried to save project without defining it, which is expected.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, not sure yet. Can you post the employer/user model and project model?

Comment: OK, so I figured it out.  The problem was on the third line of the create method.  I changed it to 'redirect_to project_path(project.id)' and it goes through the create method.  The only problem is that, as I suspected, the show method is not properly finding the project because I still get the error: 'wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)', except now the error happens with the show method.

Comment: Oh my, of course. `project_params(:id)` wouldn't work because project_params wouldn't have `id` yet because it's not saved yet! :(

Good job man.

Comment: if you add `puts "\n\n\n****#{params(:id)}****" before `@project = Project.find(params(:id))`, and redo the steps, what do you see in the rails server log?

Comment: This way we can find out if `params(:id)` has any value or not.

Comment: There's definitely params,  I checked in the console - the project was created.  It also says on the page that params(:id) = 7

Comment: Haha I figured it out.  I needed [] around :id, not ()